# Docker container communication in .NET Core

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, azure-devops

I have two .NET Core3 API's. One acts as an API and other as BFF.
Docker file and docker-compose of API as follows exposed in 5000:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: 
      context: ./TSTMaxAPI
    image: tstmaxapi:latest
    ports:
      - "5000:443"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=Admin.123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TSTMaxAPI.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./TSTMaxAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "TSTMaxAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TSTMaxAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TSTMaxAPI.dll"]
```

When I run docker-compose, I can access https://localhost:5000/weatherforecast
I can access https://localhost:5000/health
Seems OK

Now for the BFF exposed at 4000

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TSTMaxBFF.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./TSTMaxBFF.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "TSTMaxBFF.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TSTMaxBFF.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TSTMaxBFF.dll"]
```

And docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
networks:
  tst_network:
services:
  bff:
    container_name: bff
    build: 
      context: ./TSTMaxBff
    image: tstmaxbff:latest
    restart: on-failure 
    ports:
      - 4000:443
    environment:
      - API_HOST=https://api:5000
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=Admin.123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    networks:
      - tst_network
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: api
    image: tstmaxapi:latest   
    restart: on-failure  
    ports:
      - 5000:443
    networks:
      - tst_network
```

Now when I run docker-compose here, looks like both BFF and API containers are spinning up.

I can access https://localhost:4000/health
However,
I can't access https://localhost:5000/weatherforecast
I can't access https://localhost:5000/health
and
https://localhost:4000/weatherforecast, which calls API, relevant code as below

```
private static string API_URL = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API_HOST");
private static string API_ENDPOINT = API_URL + "/weatherforecast";
var response = await _client.GetStringAsync(API_ENDPOINT);
```

And getting the following error

```
SocketException: Connection refused
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: Connection refused
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

[image: Error output]

docker ps output

[image: docker ps]

I need these 2 containers to talk to each other in dev mode as well as in production mode. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what `tst_network` does here but you can try to change the host to call another service from `localhost` into `host.docker.internal` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it as there was missing certificate. Here is the final docker-compose file in case someone finds it helpful

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  bff:
    container_name: bff
    build: 
      context: ./Bff
    image: bff:latest
    restart: on-failure 
    ports:
      - 4000:443
    environment:
      - API_HOST=https://api
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=Admin.123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: api
    image: api:latest   
    restart: on-failure  
    ports:
      - 5000:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=Admin.123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, service to service communication use container port, not the publish port.

```
    environment:
      - API_HOST=https://api:5000
```

as API container port is `443`

```
    ports:
      - 5000:443
```

so the API host should be

```
    environment:
      - API_HOST=https://api:443
```

also By default, Docker runs through a non-networked UNIX socket and communicate using an HTTP socket.

Why you are enable HTTP inside the container? this should be done using Nginx or another Load balancer.

If the above did not work then you can also try with HTTP

```
API_HOST=http://api:443
```

Comment: Tried all combinations, not working still. Also, I cannot hit localhost:5000 from a browser as well.

Comment: Okay, try command inside container `curl https://localhost` and check if containers responding to this

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it. It was missing certificate so https was accessible. So https://localhost5000 was throwing error. I did try curl to get this info. Fixed it by providing proper certificate.

Comment: @RohithRaveendranPoyyeri You could [add it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), so that more members can see the useful info from your answer~